# Syntax error in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm struggling to get this .bat to work, but it keeps throwing "syntax error". This batch file should get all scheduled tasks matching the name criteria and disable them, waiting for them to terminate their execution if they're running.

Where am I going wrong?

```
schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV | findstr /i /c:"searchcriteria" | FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%f IN ('more') DO (
    :loop

    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('schtasks /query /nh /fo CSV /tn %%f ^| findstr /i /c:"running"') DO SET task=%%a

    IF [%task%] == [] (
        schtasks /change /tn %%f /DISABLE
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO loop
    )
)
```

Comment: I believe the systax error results from `if` as it does not like pipes (`|`). Perhaps try with `if not defined task`, or `if not^  defined task` (`^` plus *two* spaces)...

Comment: Tried both, still throwing "syntax error" :\

Comment: Okay... try to put parentheses around the `for` loop in addition (so you have `... | (for /F ...)`...

Comment: Nope, still throwing @aschipfl Maybe it's the %%f inside the command in the second for loop? If so how should I write it?

Comment: Now I realised there is a `goto` loop inside of a parenthesised block of code, which cannot work, because `goto` breaks the block context. I would put the `goto` loop or even the outer `for /F` loop into a sub-routine and use `call`. Furthermore, I'd put `timeout 1` into the `goto` loop in order to avoid heavy processor load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this (untested):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%F in ('schtasks /QUERY /NH /FO CSV ^| findstr /I /C:"searchcriteria"') do call :LOOP %%F
goto :EOF

:LOOP
    set "task="
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('schtasks /QUERY /NH /FO CSV /TN %1 ^| findstr /I /C:"running"') do set "task=%%A"
    if not defined task (
        schtasks /CHANGE /TN %1 /DISABLE
    ) else (
        > nul timeout 1
        goto :LOOP
    )
```

This avoids the `goto` loop to be within a parenthesised block of code, because `goto` breaks the block context. The value from the first `for /F` loop in `%%F` is 
passed to the sub-routine `:LOOP` as an argument, which is then read by `%1`.

Additionally, I replaced `more` in the first `for /F` loop by the first `schtasks`/`findstr` command line to avoid multiple pipes, like you have done it in your second `for /F` loop anyway.

Comment: I will try this on the morrow. As for the accepted answer I didn't run particularly elaborated tests apart from a quick run to see if it was working, and it did. I'm not into batch files programming and I just assumed the code to be instant-OK. My bad

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work. I changed the single quotes in the second for loop to double quotes and added parentheses for that loop.

```
schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV | findstr /i /c:"time" | FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%f IN ('more') DO (
    :loop
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ("schtasks /query /nh /fo CSV /tn %%f ^| findstr /i /c:"running"") DO (
        SET task=%%a

        IF [%task%] == [] (
            schtasks /change /tn %%f /DISABLE
        ) ELSE (
            GOTO loop
        )
    )
)
```

**Update:**
achipfl is right. His answer works for me

I tried again too and came up with the following solution. 
First it disables the sheduleing of the task and then end the task.
Then if the task is still running it calls the batch file again. I was not sure if you want to end the task. But because you like to wait for the task to finish execution I have assumed that.

```
@echo off
set querystring="time"

schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV | findstr /i /c:"%querystring%" | FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%f IN ('more') DO (
      if %%g=="running" (
        schtasks /change /tn %%f /Disable
        schtasks /end /tn %%f
      )
)
schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV | findstr /i /c:"%querystring%" | FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%f IN ('more') DO (
      if %%g=="running" (
        call test2.bat
        exit /b 0
      )
)

schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV | findstr /i /c:"%querystring%"
```

**Update 2:**
combination

```
for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%F in ('schtasks /QUERY /NH /FO CSV ^| findstr /I /C:"searchcriteria"') do call :LOOP %%F %%G
goto :EOF

:LOOP
    schtasks /CHANGE /TN %1 /DISABLE
    if %2=="running" schtasks /END /TN %1 & call :WAIT %1
    goto :EOF

:WAIT
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=," %%F IN ('schtasks /Query /nh /fo CSV /tn %1') DO set "test=%%F"
    if %test%=="running" GOTO :WAIT

:EOF
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: This is simply wrong! The single-quotes told `for /F` that the string is a command line to execute, double-quotes tells that it's a literal string! And a `goto` loop cannot be used within a parenthesised block of code! I'm really surprised your answer has been accepted...

Comment: As pointed out by @aschipfl the last for loop will never set task variable, thus always disabling the task without waiting if it's running.